# Sign out from apple using flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, logout

How can I logout from apple using flutter
I use **sign_in_with_apple** plugin + when I signin with apple and i try to print email I get null

```
 Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
    // To prevent replay attacks with the credential returned from Apple, we
    // include a nonce in the credential request. When signing in with
    // Firebase, the nonce in the id token returned by Apple, is expected to
    // match the sha256 hash of `rawNonce`.
    SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final rawNonce = generateNonce();
    final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);

    // Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
    final appleCredential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      nonce: nonce,
    );

    // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      idToken: appleCredential.identityToken,
      rawNonce: rawNonce,
    );

    prefs.setString("email", appleCredential.email.toString());
    print("hello $appleCredential");
    prefs.setString("mode", "apple");

    // Sign in the user with Firebase. If the nonce we generated earlier does
    // not match the nonce in `appleCredential.identityToken`, sign in will fail.
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomePage()), (route) => false);
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential);
  }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @HimanshuSharma yes, I used secure storage to keep my data like email and username so when it's the first time the user get connected I store his data else I use data stored. I hope the solution is clear else I can explain more.